# Transforming existing von Mises samples with new $\mu$ and $\kappa$

Tags: probability-distributions

I am trying to transform samples $x_1$ that have already been sampled from a von Mises distribution $\mathcal{V}_1(\mu_1,\kappa_1)$ to match a another von Mises distribution $\mathcal{V}_2(\mu_2, \kappa_2)$.

With normal distributions $\mathcal{N}_1(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and $\mathcal{N}_2(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$, we would do :

$$
x_{1\to2}(\mu_1, \mu_2, \sigma_1, \sigma_2) = \frac{x_1 - \mu_1}{\sigma_1} \cdot \sigma_2 + \mu_2
$$

Is there a solution to do this in the case of a von Mises distribution ?
As a subsidiary question, does this operation have a name ?

**EDIT** : transforming $x_1$ to a new location $\mu_2$ is not a problem since it corresponds to translating the pdf, and therefore the sampled variables $x_1$. We just need to care about reformating them between $[-\pi,\pi]$. It is in fact a rotation.
$$
x_{1\to2}(\mu_1, \mu_2, \kappa_1, \kappa_2=\kappa_1) = (x_1 - \mu_1 + \mu_2)[-\pi,\pi]
$$

Updating the concentration/dispersion around the mean is however more difficult.

[If we use a scaling factor, we end up with the tails of the pdfs being altered (sorry my terrible drawing).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9Px6.png)

Comment: Wouldn’t a simple transformation $X_2 := a X_1 + b$ do the trick? Pick $a$ and $b$ appropriately.

Comment: I think scaling the variables would result in the "tails" of the pdf to accumulate because the domain is periodic. The resulting pdf would not be a von Mises pdf. And the new variables would not be von Mises samples.